# Dynamic styling with ngClass and Bootstrap 4, with value of the classes retrieved from Firebase using AngularFire2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, firebase, angularfire2, bootstrap-4

I'm stuck on retrieving values from Firebase and send the value dynamically to ngClass. This is my current implementation without Firebase (local only) which works fine:

`header.component.html`

```
<h3>Header Background:</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse" (click)="setBackgroundColor('inverse')">Inverse</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="setBackgroundColor('primary')">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="setBackgroundColor('secondary')">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="setBackgroundColor('success')">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="setBackgroundColor('info')">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="setBackgroundColor('warning')">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="setBackgroundColor('danger')">Danger</button>
<hr>

<h3>Header Text Color:</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse" (click)="setTextColor('inverse')">Inverse</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="setTextColor('light')">Light</button>
<hr>

<nav [ngClass]="currentClasses">
</nav>
```

`header.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {

    currentClasses = ['navbar', 'navbar-toggleable-md', 'navbar-inverse', 'bg-inverse'];

    setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor: string) {
        switch (backgroundColor) {
            case 'inverse':
                this.currentClasses[3] = 'bg-inverse';
                break;
            case 'primary':
                this.currentClasses[3] = 'bg-primary';
                break;
            case 'secondary':
                this.currentClasses[3] = 'bg-secondary';
                break;
            case 'success':
                this.currentClasses[3] = 'bg-success';
                break;
            case 'info':
                this.currentClasses[3] = 'bg-info';
                break;
            case 'warning':
                this.currentClasses[3] = 'bg-warning';
                break;
            case 'danger':
                this.currentClasses[3] = 'bg-danger';
                break;
        }
    }

    setTextColor(textColor: string) {
        switch (textColor) {
            case 'inverse':
                this.currentClasses[2] = 'navbar-inverse';
                break;
            case 'light':
                this.currentClasses[2] = 'navbar-light';
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works fine, if I select Primary the color will change to deep blue, if I select Danger, it will change to red, etc etc

But then I want to save the value of the class in Firebase, and then update the styling dynamically in `[ngClass]` whenever the value change.

I am able to retrieve the data dynamically using the angularfire2 docs.

This is my code:
`list.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      <input type="text" #updatetext [value]="item.text" />
      <button (click)="updateItem(item.$key, updatetext.value)">Update</button>
      <button (click)="deleteItem(item.$key)">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" #newitem />
  <button (click)="addItem(newitem.value)">Add</button>
  <button (click)="deleteEverything()">Delete All</button>
  <h1>{{items | async |json}}</h1>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent {

items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('/navbar/class');
  }

  addItem(newName: string) {
    this.items.push({ text: newName });
  }
  updateItem(key: string, newText: string) {
    this.items.update(key, { text: newText });
  }
  deleteItem(key: string) {    
    this.items.remove(key); 
  }
  deleteEverything() {
    this.items.remove();
  }
}
```

And the results look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8mqJ.png

Now my problem is, I cannot find a way to bind the value of the list of classes retrieved from Firebase, to be bound to the property `[ngClass]`.

I appreciate if anyone can help me on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `[class]` directive, because i was using it for some dynamic styling like. `[class]="(aT==undefined)?'icon-sort float-right':(aT==true)?'icon-sort-alt-up float-right':'icon-sort-alt-down float-right'"`. In this example i was basing on the aT variable which kept changing in the background, so if it was undefined i would set the class to 'icon-sort float-right' else test for other conditions & so on.

The class directive bases on what you bind it to to generate a class.
You can look at this [Angular 2 dynamic styles blog](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/) for more details on ngClass and ngStyles usage.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But my problem is not in being able to use ngClass, my problem is I cannot bind the class value from firebase to my [ngClass] property.

Comment: so you need `<nav [ngClass]="currentClasses">` to render to `<nav class='navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse'>`

Comment: That's correct. and the currentClasses value will be retrieved from Firebase using AngularFire2. But I just can't figure out how to do it. I suppose it has to do with Observable.

Comment: So when you `console.log` the this.items in the constructor of `list.component.ts` what does it give.